# How To Adjust Height of Text Box based on Length of Text/String

Tags: vba, excel

This is more of a conceptual problem. As it says in the title, I would like to create a Function or Sub-Module that is capable of taking text from a cell and putting it into a text box on a form; then, I would like the text box to adjust its height based on the length of the text in that cell. I have done some research without much success, except for some outdated posts. I wish to understand if you can compare the length of the string to the width of a text box numerically, or if there is a simple way to calculate the string's width. The font I am using is Tahoma size 10.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: I'd suggest moving to a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) and then you can calculate the required width of the TextBox based on the font size.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for function. Use what Excel provides

> Right click | Format Shape | Text Box
>
> Under Auto Fit section
>
> Check "Resize Shape to fit text"
>
> Uncheck "Allow text to overflow shape"

**Edited for UserForm textbox**

> Set AutoSize = True
>
> Set Multiline = True

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to put a text box in a **form**, not on the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Can't you set the Autosize flag to true?

Comment: If you want the height to change and not the width then set MultiLine to true as well